# NSNotificationCenter removeObserver not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
            NSOperationQueue *mainQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification object:nil queue:mainQueue usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                    NSLog(@"SShot");
            }];
        }

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification object:nil];
    NSLog(@"VWD");
        }

 -(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification object:nil];
        NSLog(@"VDD");
    }
```

I am getting `SShot` logged in console even after I have removed the observer.

Is there any other way to remove `UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification` observer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:):

> To unregister observations, **you pass the object returned** by this
>   method to removeObserver:. You must invoke removeObserver: or
>   removeObserver:name:object: before any object specified by
>   addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock: is deallocated.

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center removeObserver:self.localeChangeObserver];
```

You're trying to remove the worng observer, `self` is not the observer here, the observer is the object returned by the add method

Answer (score 21):

Here is how to do it in Swift 4...

```
    private var observer: Any!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("SomeNotification"), object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
            //do something
        }
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Harris code is correct except a small detail that for Swift 4 it is now

private var observer: Any! and not private var observer: NSObjectProtocol! 
So code should be:

```
private var observer: Any!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("SomeNotification"), object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
        //do something
    }
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

To **Add Observer**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(userDidTakeScreenshot) name:UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)userDidTakeScreenshot {
    // Screenshot taken, act accordingly.
}
```

And to **Remove a Particular Observer**

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification object:nil];
}
```

to **Remove All Observer**

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    }
```

Let me know if it worked for you !!!!